# Editor that can do code completion from json schema

Tags: json, jsonschema

I am using a script engine that uses json schemas to validate json files.
Have you seen any editor that can do code completion according to a json schema?

I am working on a mac.

Regards
Christian

Answer (score 1):

[Visual Studio 2013 from update 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/04/11/intellisense-for-json-schema-in-the-json-editor.aspx).